# Exclude weekends in PowerBI report?

Tags: powerbi

I have a burn down chart for our VS Team Services project in Power BI - so that we can report on story points and not effort remaining.

In the chart, I have Date on the X axis. Is there a way to filter out weekend dates from the chart? There is no activity on the weekend.

I found [this forum post](http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Date-weekends-and-holidays/td-p/15469), however I didn't understand how to add this to our report.

Comment: Do you have 'day of week' column in your dataset ? If yes, then you can simply add a Report / Page level filter and exclude Saturday and Sunday from the Report...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have 'day of week' column in your dataset ? If yes, then you can simply add a Report / Page level filter and exclude Saturday and Sunday from the Report...

Comment: It was `Day Name` in the VSTS data set. I was able to add a Page filter specifying Monday-Friday as the visible range.

Answer (score 7):

One way of achieving this:

- Add a calculated column of form `IsWeekend = IF(WEEKDAY(Table1[date])>5,1,0)`
- Filter your visual by `IsWeekend is 0`
- Go to visual format (brush icon) -> X-Axis ->  Scale Type -> Type -> Categorical.

Comment: I understand how this would have worked. Thanks! In the end, there was a `Day Name` that I could use.

Comment: I was missing the `Categorical` part. Thanks a lot!